# Issues using window.opener in all browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-9

Okay, I'm having serious problems here. On my own computer, this code works just fine. But on my coworkers, it breaks in IE and Firefox.

`var openlocation = window.opener.location.href;`

breaks for "Permission Denied", on the window.opener part. So, on the opener page, I wrote a function that's stored in an external .js page:

```
var getLocation = function() {
    return window.location.href;
};
```

and then calling that, like
`var openlocation = window.opener.getLocation();`

Does anyone have any idea why this is breaking?

Edit: One page is creating the popup, and they're both on the same domain.
The popup page has the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var openlocation = window.opener.getLocation();
    (function setTimer() {
        setInterval(function () {
            if (window.opener.location.href != openlocation) {    // they've changed screens
                window.close();
            }
        }, 15000);
    })();
  $("input#notescancel").click(function () {
        window.close();
  });
});
```

I've tried with both my `getLocation()` function and just using `window.opener.location.href` but, for all computers but mine, it breaks.
Thanks.

Comment: If they're same-domain, this should work.  Can you point to a testcase?

Comment: Should but don't. I don't have any public-facing sites I can put up test pages on, but I'll post the full code in the OP.

Comment: Are they on different subdomains? Also check browser security settings.

Comment: Same subdomains. I've done some searching on SO and Google and have found that typically, window.opener is pretty reliable. I'm at a loss here, and while I can cull this bit of functionality to make it work.. I'd rather not.

Comment: At this point, I'd like to understand what exact steps to reproduce you're using.  You load the opener page.  It opens the popup.  Then you navigate the opener page, right?  Where do you navigate it to?

Comment: Any other page. This is for something like internal notes for the company I work for, and the page that opens the popup is dynamic, and be used for different items. So the notes for one item wouldn't apply to another; to prevent confusion on the users' part, I'd rather close the popup if they navigate away from the original page they were on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was going to deep into window.opener.location - for IE, I should stop it there, convert it to a string, and call it good. Which is what I did, and it now works.

So, instead of window.opener.location.href, I just used window.opener.location.toString() for IE.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because that the 2 windows are on different domains. Even sample.com and www.sample.com are considered different by the browser. Technically its called Same Origin Policy,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: I suppose I should've put more information in here. The domains are the same, updated OP.